# Fancybox 2: auto resize the iFrame height for tabbed content

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2

I use Fancybox2 to open an iFrame popup window (content comes from the same website). Within this popup, I have tabbed content (Bootstrap tabs). Each tab has content of different heights.

I am hoping that Fancybox can resize its height accordingly when I click tabs to see content on different heights.

I tried different combinations of autoSiz, autoHeight, etc. Got no success. Googled, and it seems many people asked related questions.

Am I missing something? Or is it doable? I feel this should be an easy configuration.

Thanks!

Comment: what about triggering `$.fancybox.update()` (v2.x) after the tab selector event? (you may also need set `fitToView` to `false`)

Comment: I am trying to attach click event to the A tag of the tabs. But the click event does not get fired. I guest it is caused by iFrame issue? Thanks so much for your input!

Comment: @JFK, i was able to resize the iFrame height for tabs according to what you said by directly adding (not through jQuery) onclick="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.update();return false;" to each tab selector. Could you please post this and I choose it as the answer? It is your credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to trigger the `$.fancybox.update()` (fancybox v2.x) method after the tab selector event

If using *iframes*, try `parent.$.fancybox.update()`

You may also need set `fitToView` to `false`